# Gazebo 11.10 no namespaces found issue

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-11, ros-iron

I'm using ROS2 iron for a robot I have using URDF and XACRO on Ubuntu 22.04, which seems to be working fine in RViz. After trying to spawn it, I ran into a "No Namespaces Found" error, and later found out it had to do with Gazebo in particular.

From what I've read, the problem is in the lack of models in ~/.gazebo/models/ and the fix would be to download them via `wget -r -R "index\.html*" http://gazebosim.org/models` but even after doing that I face the same issue. Same for older models in `https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/`

I also uploaded my project quickly into The Construct, and it launches in Gazebo just fine. However, I'd rather stick with my Ubuntu VM and fix the issue from there.

Below's an example output of what I'm getting when just running Gazebo. It doesn't matter what world I use (or don't use). I'd assume if I make it past this error then my robot will work in the VM.

```
$ gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/blank.world --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/blank.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
[Msg] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Wrn] [Server.cc:579] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Err] [Server.cc:584] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up.
[Err] [Node.cc:118] No namespaces found
^Cescalating to SIGKILL on server
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really much of a solution per se, but right now my only real workaround is to transition from Gazebo11 to Ignition Gazebo. What works for my set up is Ros2 Iron + Ubuntu 22.04 + Ignition Gazebo Harmonic.

After a few changes to my gazebo launch file, i.e. using the package 'ros_gz_sim' instead of 'gazebo_ros', then everything works fine. This must be a general problem with using Gazebo11 and Ros2 Iron (possibly even Humble from what I read online), which I wasn't aware of at the time, so I'd just recommend the switch to get everything working.